# Analytic solution of a Graetz bridge rectifier with inductive filter

Tags: analog, education

how could I solve the following circuit?

[image]

In particular I would find the analytic expression of current on inductor. I tried to solve the differential equation (hps: S1 and S4 on):

$$L \cdot \frac{di}{dt}+R \cdot i = sin(t)$$

which solution is (if R=1 and L=1):

$$i(t)=C \cdot e^{-t}+\frac {\sqrt(2)}{2} \cdot cos\left(t-\frac{3 \cdot \pi}{4}\right)$$ 
If 
$$i(0)=0$$ 
then 
$$L \cdot \frac{di}{dt}+R \cdot i = sin(t)$$ whose solution is: $$i(t)= \frac{1}{2} \cdot e^{-t}+\frac {\sqrt(2)}{2} \cdot cos\left(t-\frac{3 \cdot \pi}{4}\right)$$
This solution is right until i>0, after I solved again the differential equation with the same initial condition, but my plot is not the same of LTSpice.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that you will have to address to find an analytic solution to your problem. First, the forcing function you are using is not taking into account the rectification from your ideal diodes, i.e., the function you should be using for your forcing function is a rectified sine. You can either use:
\begin{equation}
g(t) = |\sin(t)|,
\end{equation}
or,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 g(t) &= \sin(t) \qquad t\in [0,\frac{T}{2}) \\
&= -\sin(t) \qquad t\in[\frac{T}{2},T].
\end{split}
\end{equation}

You could also set this up as an alternating series, but I think using the absolute value function as your forcing function and making a periodic extension of the result will be the easiest.

Second, I'm not familiar with LTSPICE, but you have your *voltage* source set as \$\sin(t)\$, you could replace it with a *current* source instead (if that option is available). So your initial condition \$i(t) = 0\$ is not correct.

Comment: Hi @Captainj2001, to default LTSpice set \$i(t) = 0\$ on inductor.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I'm not planning on simulating this, regardless of what initial condition you force you are still rectifying the sine wave so you should redo your analysis using the above functions for the specified time periods.